# How to read array of files in a factory in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have an array of files. I want to read all of them and make a json array out of it. The problem is that `d3.csv`is an asynchronous function.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222395/angular-js-async-factory-call-issue) question, I have come to know that `$q.defer()` has to be used to returned deferred promise to the controller.

My problem is that I have to read an array of files and make corresponding array of objects.

Here is the code so far:

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function($q) {

  var masterData=[];

  var visFolder = "/data/";
  var files=[(visFolder + "Crime_full1.csv"),(visFolder + "accidents.csv"),(visFolder + "health.csv")];


  return {
      // Get all masterData
      get: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        //I want to read all the files in array 
        d3.csv(files[0], function(d) {
          masterData.push(d);
          deferred.resolve(masterData);
          console.log("a csv file read");
        });

        return deferred.promise;

      }

    }
  });


myApp.controller('visCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams,myFactory) {

  myFactory.get().then(function(masterData) {

    //masterdata should contain data of all the files in an array
    $scope.masterData = masterData;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over the files array and call the function that calls d3 library for each file. This function should return promise. The `getFile` function below does the same:

```
getFile = function (file) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    d3.csv(file, function (d) {
        deferred.resolve(d);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The `getFile` function is defined outside the return block. The `get` function now has to be updated to call `getFile` with each file and then collate the results with `$q.all`. The code would look something like this.

```
get: function () {

    var promises = files.map(function (f) {
        return getFile(f);
    });

    return $q.all(promises).then(function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (f) {
            masterData.push(f);
        });
        return masterData;
    });
}
```